# chromium webdriver errors making it impossible for me to run a python project

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chromium

I cloned a repo from 4 years ago for a scraping project that uses python with the following packages: `selenium`, `beautifulsoup4`, and `Xlsxwriter`. It seems that chromium made changes to the way the webdriver function works based on what I read online to something like this:

```
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = '/PATH')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service).
```

How do I get this project to continue running? Is there a way to only import chromium of a specific version and keep the code how it was before: `driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver.exe')`?

I keep getting this error code:

```
AttributeError:
'str' object has no attribute "capabilities'
 
"/us/local/Lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder-py", Line 40, in get_path
msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities [browserName 'I} using Selenium
```

I changed this line of the code: `driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver.exe')`
to this:

```
service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = '/PATH')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```